# Use index.js to import multiple image assets in React

Tags: node.js, image, reactjs, import, export

I have been using a pattern of collecting component files for export with `index.js` files placed in directories, for example:

```
// index.js file in /components directory
export { Splash } from './Splash'
export { Portfolio } from './Porfolio'
export { Contact } from './Contact'
```

In `Layout.js` (located in root directory) I can neatly import with one call:

```
import { Splash, Portfolio, Contact } from '.'
```

I use this pattern a lot as I structure components across directories and sub-directories.

My specific question is to ask if there is any way to extend this pattern to image assets collected in `src/assets/img`?  Can I place an `index.js` file in my images directory and to be able to call groups of images to a component?

```
//index.js in /src/assets/img directory
export { Img01 } from './img-01.png'
export { Img02 } from './img-02.jpg'
export { Img03 } from './img-03.svg'

//Call in Component.js
import { Img01, Img02, Img03 } from '../assets/img'
```

I think this should be achievable, but I can't figure out the correct syntax or modifications required to this pattern.  Any code samples or recommendations for better practices are appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using CRA? What are you using for image asset loading? Webpack?

Comment: Good point, I should have declared that I am using webpack 3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you are using webpack take a look at this [require](https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/#require-context). You can use require to import a file like the example below:

*tree directory*

```
-images 
  |_index.js
  |_notification.png
  |_logo.png
-pages
  |-home.js
```

*images/index.js*

```
export const notification = require('./notification.png')
export const logo = require('./logo.png')
```

*pages/home.js*

```
import { notification } from '../images/'
<img src={notification} />
```

i hope i helped you

Comment: Hey, this is the syntax I was looking for, thanks!  Makes sense to declare the images as `const` and requiring the asset.

Comment: Small typo; tree directory says 'image' but imports are from 'images'.

Answer (score 12):

To `export` default components do it like this:

```
export { default as Splash } from './Splash'
export { default as Portfolio } from './Porfolio'
export { default as Contact } from './Contact'

// you dont need to include the 'index' on the route, just do './' if you 
// are in the same directory, but your export file must be named index.js
import { Splash, Portfolio, Contact } from './';
```

To export files: images, css, .svg etc, just include the file extension:

```
export { default as Img01 } from './img-01.png'
export { default as Img02 } from './img-02.jpg'
export { default as Img03 } from './img-03.svg'
```

//Call in Component.js

```
import { Img01, Img02, Img03 } from '../assets/img'
```

Comment: The selected answer did not work for me. This one worked.