# How to Bulk Export my Images in an Index,js file in React Native

Tags: react-native

I tried to Export multiple images in an index.js file to import more efficiently however Images dont load and there is blank space in their place. I am new to react native.

```
├── Assets
│   ├── images
│   │   ├── img1.png
│   |   ├── img2.png
│   |   ├── index.js
│   |
```

this is my index.js that contains needed Images

```
import FingerPrint from "./FingerPrint.png";
import FullBrand from "./BrandLarger.png";
import LogInBG from "./LogInBG.png";
import NBEBrand from "./NBEBrand.png";
import NBELogo from "./NBELogo.png";

export default {FingerPrint, FullBrand, LogInBG, NBEBrand, NBELogo};
```

This is how I TRY to import images wherever needed.

```
import {FingerPrint} from "../assets/images";
```

And This is how I try to use the images.

```
<Image source={FingerPrint} />
```

I get no console errors whatsoever and I am actually lost due to the difference between react and react native.

Answer (score 0):

So in your case it would be:

index.js

```
export const FingerPrint require("./FingerPrint.png");
export const FullBrand require("./BrandLarger.png");
```

and where you use it

```
import {FingerPrint} from "../assets/images";
```

I tried this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47614857/4638462) and it worked for me